# How to pass multiple parameters for the same commandline argument?

Tags: perl, command-line

Scenario: I need to pass names of multiple tv shows to a script:
Eg. `./script -a "Homeworld" -a "Supernatural"`

I'm using Getopt::Long::Configure to get the options.

```
sub ArgParser
{
    my ($help,$addshow,$delshow,$checkshow,$listshows) = ();
    GetOptions ('help|h' => \$help,             
                'add|a=s' => \$addshow,             
                );
    if ($help)
    {
        HelpPrint;      
    }
    elsif ($addshow)
    {
        say $addshow;       
    }   
    else 
    {        
        HelpPrint("Invalid option or no options specified!");
    }
    exit;
}

ArgParser;
```

Currently, only the last specified argument is being received by the script. How can I detect whether multiple parameters to the same argument are being passed on the command line?

@ARGV does contain all arguments, so how can I use them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just pass the argument with a separator:

[Options with multiple values](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-multiple-values)

> Often it is useful to allow comma-separated lists of values as well as
>   multiple occurrences of the options. This is easy using Perl's split()
>   and join() operators:
>
> ```
>     GetOptions ("library=s" => \@libfiles);
>     @libfiles = split(/,/,join(',',@libfiles));
> ```

Or another option is:

> ```
>     --library lib/stdlib --library lib/extlib
> ```
>
> To accomplish this behaviour, simply specify an array reference as the
>   destination for the option:
>
> ```
>     GetOptions ("library=s" => \@libfiles);
> ```

Using the first example, your command line would be:

```
./script -a "Homeworld" -a "Supernatural" -a "Breaking Bad"
   -or-
./script -a "Homeworld,Supernatural,Breaking Bad"
   -or-
./script -a "Homeworld,Supernatural" -a "Breaking Bad"
```

Using the second example, your command line would be:

```
./script -a "Homeworld" -a "Supernatural" -a "Expanse, The"
```